# WordPress local site is repeating domain and breaking

Tags: wordpress, web, localhost, mamp, web-deployment

I double checked my DB. The site keeps trying to pull from localhost/foo/localhost/foo from just localhost/foo

Comment: check your option table  with option_name home that recides in id 36 or you can past your htaccess code

Answer (score 0):

Does it happen when you login from `localhost/foo/wp-login.php` ?

If yes go to your `options` table and update both `siteurl` and `home` to   `http://localhost/foo`

Comment: in your `siteurl` and `home`?

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed after I added 'http://' in front of localhost. I didn't think I needed to do that but I guess I do.